# HTTP file upload in Express NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, express, upload, multer, formidable

I have an Express NodeJS server. I would like to upload very large files (more than 10Gb of size). I tried modules `multer` and `formidable` for this purpose.

My problem is that I am not able to receive more than 1Gb in the server. In the browser I get `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. No error thrown by the server code.

My code with `formidable`:

```
var formidable = require("formidable");
form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.uploadDir = "./files/";
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    console.log("received upload");
});
```

My code with `multer`:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "./files")
    }
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage}).array("file",2);

/** ------ **/

upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error");
        } else { //success!
            console.log("received upload");
        }
});
```

Do you have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

No need of using multer. try with this code.

```
var formidable = require("formidable");
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

            form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {


            });

            form.on('end', function(fields, files, data) {

                var temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
                var file_name = openedFiles[0].name; 

                var new_location = 'public/images/';

                    fs.move(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err) { 
                        if ( err ) console.log(err);
                        else
                            console.log('upload-photo success');
                    });
            });
```